# Case statement only runs one condition

Tags: vb.net, case, conditional-statements, statements

hey when I enter an integer into my case statement it produces the right output but with a string it just produces the same result each time, do you guys know any solutions?

```
     Select Case Grades.Text
        Case = "A*"
            score = score + 100
            MessageBox.Show("You entered an A*")
            Gcount = Gcount + 1

        Case >= 90
            score = score + 100
            MessageBox.Show("You entered an A*")
            Gcount = Gcount + 1

        Case = "A"
            score = score + 85
            MessageBox.Show("You entered an A")
            Gcount = Gcount + 1
            MessageBox.Show(Gcount)

        Case < 90 And Grades.Text >= 80
            score = score + 85
            MessageBox.Show("You entered an A")
            Gcount = Gcount + 1
            MessageBox.Show(Gcount)

        Case = "B"
            score = score + 75
            MessageBox.Show("You entered a B")
            Gcount = Gcount + 1
            MessageBox.Show(score)

        Case < 80 And Grades.Text >= 70
            score = score + 75
            MessageBox.Show("You entered a B")
            Gcount = Gcount + 1

        Case = "C"
            score = score + 65
            MessageBox.Show("You entered a C")
            Gcount = Gcount + 1

        Case < 70 And Grades.Text >= 60
            score = score + 65
            MessageBox.Show("You entered a C")
            Gcount = Gcount + 1
```

Comment: That ought not compile using Option Strict.  `Select Case Grades.Text` promises a string, while `Case < 70` is testing an integer.  AndAlso use `AndAlso` instead of `And`

Comment: You cannot use `And` nor `AndAlso` in a Select Case statement like this.

Comment: For a failsafe, still simple code (in this case) I think you'll have to use an `If`-statement instead.

Comment: Yes. Select Case will only execute the first true statement that it finds.

Answer (score 0):

You should set Option Strict On.

So there is a way like this

```
Select case True
  Case intVariable <= 90
    ' do something...
  Case 91 < intVariable AndAlso intVariable <= 100
    ' do something...
  Case 100 < intVariable AndAlso intVariable <= 110
    ' do something... and so on
End Select
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    Select Case Grades.Text
        Case Is >= 90
            MessageBox.Show("You entered an A*")
        Case Is < 90 And Grades.Text >= 80
            MessageBox.Show("You entered an A")
        Case Is < 80 And Grades.Text >= 70
            MessageBox.Show("You entered a B")
        Case Is < 70 And Grades.Text >= 60
            MessageBox.Show("You entered a C")
    End Select
```

Comment: Won't work, one cannot use `And` or `AndAlso` in a Select Case statement like this. `And` will perform a bitwise operation, and `AndAlso` will return `True` or `False`. And since `Grades.Text` will probably never evaluate to the string `"True"` this won't work.